# How to counts the corner points in the image of a given color

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I hope you are doing well.
I want to count the corner points in the image of a given color. Like blue colour has two shapes how can i find and count that corner points

[image: Input Image]

I have used the following code But It find out the corner of shape not color

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def cornerpoint(img):
    img = cv2.imread(img)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = np.float32(gray)
    dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,5,3,0.04)
    ret, dst = cv2.threshold(dst,0.1*dst.max(),255,0)
    dst = np.uint8(dst)
    ret, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(dst)
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.001)
    corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,np.float32(centroids),(5,5),(-1,-1),criteria)
    for i in range(1, len(corners)):
        print(corners[i])
    img[dst>0.1*dst.max()]=[0,0,0]
    plt.imshow(img)

cornerpoint('/content/shapes.png')
```

How can I proceed to count the corner points in the image of a given color?

Comment: get the blue stuff only https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html

Comment: Is this the real image or just an explanatory diagram ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust it is real image i want to process this image

Comment: @Piglet but this like is tracker bar i don't want to use it

Comment: The filtering on color is not too difficult (erase all pixels that are not very close to a pure color).

Comment: See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/

Comment: Do you count the inner corners as well ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes count inner corners as well

Comment: @fmw42 this is shape detection not color-based detection

Comment: You can try your luck with a Harris corner detector.

Comment: @YvesDaoust i have tried but first we need to detect what are the color in image

Comment: Follow my previous hint.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How can I do that Can you share example/code

Comment: Read all comments.

Comment: @YvesDaoust mean there is no solution?

Comment: what's "but this like is tracker bar i don't want to use it " supposed to mean? you're talking in riddles

Comment: Just get a list of unique colors in the image and ignore the white background.  See np.unique()

Comment: @fmw42: due to antialiasing of the edges, there will be hundreds of unique colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to questions raised in the comments, here is one way to get the list of unique colors ignoring the anti-aliasing of the colors.

*(You could also use morphology to thin your colored lines to remove the anti-aliased pixels)*

- Read the input
- Reshape to 1D image of 3 channels
- Use np.unique to get the colors and counts
- Zip the colors and counts
- Put the zip into a list
- Sort the zipped list on count in reverse order
- Print only those colors that have counts above some threshold.
- (Note: other filters could be used to check colors against each other to be sure not too close or to remove colors near the background color. Etc)

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('colored_polygons.png')

# reshape img to 1 column of 3 colors
# -1 means figure out how big it needs to be for that dimension
img2 = img.reshape(-1,3)

# get the unique colors
colors, counts = np.unique(img2, return_counts=True, axis=0)

# zip colors, counts
unique = zip(colors,counts)

# make list of color, count
cc_list = []
for color, count in unique:
    cc_list.append((color, count))
    
# function to define key as second element (count)
def takeSecond(elem):
    return elem[1]

# sort cc_list on counts
cc_list.sort(key=takeSecond, reverse=True)

# print sorted list and threshold on count
index = 0
for item in cc_list:
    color = item[0]
    count = item[1]
    if count > 5000:
        index += 1
        print("index:", index, "count:", count, "color:", color)
```

List of Top Unique Colors:

```
index: 1 count: 428771 color: [255 255 255]
index: 2 count: 15735 color: [0 0 0]
index: 3 count: 9760 color: [ 14 127   0]
index: 4 count: 9160 color: [255  38   0]
index: 5 count: 8893 color: [  0   0 255]
```